# How does the client know which data to put in an HTTP GET request?

Tags: http, cookies

The question is pretty much in the title, how the client knows which values to put in the field `Cookie` of the following HTTP GET request header?

```
GET / HTTP/2
Host: www.somewebsite.com
User-Agent: MYUSERAGENT
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: atuserid=SOMETHING; atauthority=SOMETHING; didomi_token=SOMETHING; ...
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
TE: trailers
```

It tried to search everywhere I could but I did not find the answer.

From what I found in some responses there is a `Set-Cookie` value. But this is a different case because the request above is the very first request of the client to the server.

Thanks for your help!